# Destructuring object based on expression

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, expression, destructuring

I want to know if you can use a dynamic expression when destructing an object:

Assume:

```
//basic de-structure example
var a = {b: 1};
var {b: c} = a; // stores 1 in c
//what I want to do
var { (b > 0): isItHigher = false} = a; // want isItHigher to be true
```

It might be a syntax I am not aware of, but, essentially, I want to evaluate an expression against the original object property and store it in a new variable. Is this possible?

Comment: It’s unclear why exactly you need this. Could you perhaps give another example? Do you need multiple `isItHigher`s for multiple values? You could maybe simply use the ternary operator, although it’s not really clear which values `isItHigher` is supposed to have.

Comment: De-structuring provides me a terse way to initialize multiple variables from an object. I use it often to read variables from nested objects. Often times you need to derive further information from aforementioned variables. Such is the case by which I would want to do this.

Comment: Is your example's last line equivalent to `var isItHigher = a.b > 0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by using [destructuring defaults](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values). The defaults can also include expressions based on values you've already extracted:

```js
var a = { b: 1 };
var { b,  isItHigher = b > 0 } = a;

console.log(isItHigher);
```

[@Anko notes a caveat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514203/destructuring-object-based-on-expression/41514409?noredirect=1#comment70235104_41514409): This method also creates a variable `b`, which may needlessly pollute the namespace depending on context.

Comment: Thanks. One minor update to your answer is that your comment is inaccurate - but the concept is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Caveat: This method also creates a variable `b`, which may needlessly pollute the namespace depending on context.

Comment: @Anko - indeed. I wouldn't do it on the global context, but inside of functions, and modules it's not an issue usually. I'll add that as a note to my answer.

Comment: Another problem with this approach arises when the object to destructure has itself a property named "isItHigher". In this case the default expression wouldn't be executed at all and instead the value of that object property would be assigned.